# c++ infinite loop: recursive function

Tags: c++, string, recursion, infinite-loop

So when I run this function with ***string str ("A:1,B:1");*** as an input from the main, I get into an infinite loop and then a segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
void function (string str)
{
    if (!str.empty() || str.at(0) != ',')
    {
        if (isalpha(str.at(0)))
        {   
            if (str.find(',') != string::npos)
            {
                write(str.substr (0,str.find(','))); //takes this to another function to write in a file
                function (str.substr (str.find(',')+1,str.length()-1));
            }
        else
        {
            write(str.substr (0,str.length()));
        }
    }
}
```

would anyone be able to shed some light here?
How could I get the code to separate A:1 and B:1 and send them individually to the write function. The example I used is a simple one but I will be using longer lines of strings.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Read about how to ask questions here. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking  Pay particular attention to "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"

Comment: Hello, and thank you. Could you be more specific please? What didn't I mention in my question that you would have liked to see? @JiveDadson

Comment: What part of "Read this" do you not understand?

Comment: You have unbalanced `{ }`. Once fixed (according to tab), code seems to works: [Demo](https://ideone.com/wcwSPU).

Comment: @Jarod42 - That is the least of his problems. When the brackets are closed, it will crash on certain inputs, and once THAT's fixed, it still won't do what he intends.

Comment: @JiveDadson I'm afraid you didn't understand what I mean. I read the section you asked me to but I would like you to point out why my question didn't meet your expectations. Are you talking about the use of tabs? What part of 'more specific' don't you understand?

Comment: @abc Provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problems, to start with. Is that specific enough?

Comment: You are a mighty fast reader. The code is not a complete program that we can compile and test. MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I see that your recursive function does not use the correct string length.

```
function (str.substr (str.find(',')+1,str.length()-1));
```

`substr` function of string class takes length as the second parameter. In your case the length should be something like `str.length() - str.find(',') - 1`. Otherwise you are accessing outside of original string memory.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    if (isalpha(str.at(0)))
>    {
> ```

There is no closing `}` for the `{`.

As far as [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) is concerned, it's an old C function with a very user-unfriendly interface. It practically forces you to cast the argument to `unsigned char` in order to avoid undefined behaviour. So make it:

```
if (isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(str.at(0)))) {
```

> `!str.empty() || str.at(0) != ','`

cannot be right. It reads as *"if the string isn't empty or if it's empty and its first character isn't a comma"* - This will cause an exception to be thrown for empty strings. You probably meant `&&` instead of `||`.

> I get into an infinite loop and then a segmentation fault (core dumped)

There is no loop in your code. What very likely happens is that your `write` function calls `function` in a way that causes infinite recursion (e.g. simply via `function("A:1,B:1");`), and eventually a stack overflow.